# Dscp value in IP header for TCP SYN/SYN ACK

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, ip, qos

I have TCP client and server sockets and I have set the socket option IP_TOS on both the client and server socket with different values(say `Client dscp = 0x21 and Server Dscp = 0x38`).
Now when I am trying to connect to the server the syn Packet contains dscp value 0x21 but the Syn ack packet from the server does not contain dscp 0x38 instead it is same as client i.e. 0x21.

Is this the correct behaviour??

Consider both server and client is linux Socket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the correct behaviour. Any ACK packet including a SYN/ACK belongs to the stream it is ACK-ing, so it obeys the sequencing, TOS, etc, of that stream.

Comment: Is there any setting or option so that the dscp value in Ack will be same as value set at server socket?